# validation on a usercontrol on aspx page using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a user control that contains 3 dropdown for(date,month, year).I have called this user control on aspx page.

Please select Date From.

On my aspx page all fields are validated with javascript validation.
when I select date from this user control (not month & year) ,and click on submit button, it shows the error message.
but my problem is that if i select year (not date,month) then in this case neither it  fire the error message nor it saves the data.
I want that it fired the message everytime when atleast one field(day,month,year) is not selected.I want to handle this problem on clentside. Please give me your suggetion.

```
function InputValidation(vg) {
    var isValid = true;
    try {
        var j = 0;
        var inputCtrlArr = new Array();
        var key = 'block';
        var inputIntputArr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var inputDdlArr = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        var inputTextareaArr = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        var c = 0;
        for (var i = 0; inputIntputArr.length > i; i++) inputCtrlArr[c++] = inputIntputArr[i];
        for (var i = 0; inputDdlArr.length > i; i++) inputCtrlArr[c++] = inputDdlArr[i];
        for (var i = 0; inputTextareaArr.length > i; i++) inputCtrlArr[c++] = inputTextareaArr[i];
        for (var i = 0; inputCtrlArr.length > i; i++) {
            if (inputCtrlArr[i].getAttribute('required') == 'true' && inputCtrlArr[i].getAttribute('vg') == vg) {
                if (inputCtrlArr[i].value.trim() == '') {
                    //errinputReqCtrlArr[j++] = inputCtrlArr[i];
                    key = 'block';

                    isValid = false;
                }
                else {
                    key = 'none';
                }
                if (inputCtrlArr[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    if (inputCtrlArr[i].checked == false) {
                        //errinputReqCtrlArr[j++] = inputCtrlArr[i];
                        key = 'block';

                        isValid = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        key = 'none';
                    }
                }
                var errorDivId = inputCtrlArr[i].getAttribute('ErrorDivId');
                var objErrorDivId = document.getElementById(errorDivId);
                if (objErrorDivId != null) objErrorDivId.style.display = key;
            }
        }
 }
    catch (ex) { }

}



function InputCntrlValidate(obj) {
    try {
        if (obj.getAttribute('required') == 'true') {
            if (obj.value == '') {
                key = 'block';
            }
            else {
                key = 'none';
            }
            var errorDivId = obj.getAttribute('ErrorDivId');
            var objErrorDivId = document.getElementById(errorDivId);
            if (objErrorDivId != null) objErrorDivId.style.display = key;
        }
    } catch (ex) { }
}




function sanitizeInput(obj) {

    if (obj.getAttribute('msg') == obj.value) {
        alert("same value");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [calendar contro](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)l on the [AjaxControlToolKit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) if it were me. No validation required then other than if the field is mandatory. It's a lot easier and looks a lot better. All client side.

Just down load the ajxcontrolkit dll and include in your project and use as per any custom control/third party component.

**EDIT:**

Ok if you just want at least one drop down to be selected then try JQuery e.g.

```
function isDropDownsValid()
{
var isValid = true;
$('select').map(function()
            {
                if($(this).val() == -1)
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            });
return isValid;
}
```

Then wire into your submit button like so

```
  <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="return isDropDownsValid" Text="Submit />
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crabbucket/d7aXm/) with a demo. You may need to change the selector `$('select')` to target the exact dropdowns you need.

Comment: Thanks 4 reply.
But it is the client requirement 3 dropdown for date selection.
So i cant use calender control.

Comment: @user1029679. I've added a JQuery method to do what you want. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your JavaScript. Since if it is working for the one dropdownlist then it should work for other two. Further you will have to check for month and date. If it is feb then the days should be 28 or 29 and it will depend on the year. So lots of effort will require to solve it.

Comment: my dropdown shows days according to month and leap year. all 3 dropdowns are in a usercontrol and i have implemented the Required=true on usercontrol's tagprefix.
It shows error message only in sequence first for date then for month & then for year.
but if i select in reverse order(first year) or from middle(first month & year) and left the date field blank then it does not show the error message

Answer (score 0):

You only need three `RequiredFieldValidators` with each `ControlToValidate` leading to one of your `DropDownLists`. If you've a default value of f.e. "please select" you should set this as [InitialValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) of the Validators.

Here is a sample(i've only added few ListItems instead of all for dates,months and years):

```
    <asp:DropDownlist ID="DdlDate" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="please select" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownlist>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqDate" 
        ControlToValidate="DdlDate" 
        InitialValue="please select" 
        ErrorMessage="Please select Date"
        Display="Dynamic"
        runat="server">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:DropDownlist ID="DdlMonth" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="please select" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="January"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="February"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="March"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownlist>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqMonth" 
        ControlToValidate="DdlMonth" 
        InitialValue="please select" 
        ErrorMessage="Please select Month"
        Display="Dynamic"
        runat="server" >
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:DropDownlist ID="DdlYear" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="please select" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2010"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2011"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2012"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownlist>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqYear" 
        ControlToValidate="DdlYear" 
        InitialValue="please select" 
        ErrorMessage="Please select Year"
        Display="Dynamic"
        runat="server" >
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cant do this bcoz it is a user control and in my application this control is used everywhere for date selection and in my whole application all validation are client side.If I use RequiredValidator it reuires a lot of wrk. I have to change everywhere for required validator.

Comment: @user1029679: i thought the DropDownLists would be in the UserControl. So you simply need to add the Validators to it. By default they are validating on client-side(and also on serverside if necessary).